# Why IE8 reloads the site after calling a ajax function?

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-8

If I tab through my form there is the nickname-field with a `onBlur="validate();"`. While tabbing to the next input there should be a validation of the nickname and if fails a proposol appears.

Works fine in all browsers but IE8. I only call `jQuery.get`, split the data and slideDown the proposals.

```
jQuery.get(requestMappingLoginCheck, map, function(data) { 
    var splitted = data.split(";");             
    jQuery.each(splitted, function(index,value) {
        proposals += '<span style="display:block;"><input type="radio" name="loginproposals" value="' + value + '" id="proposal_' + index + '" onclick="changeLoginField(this);"><label for="proposal_' + index + '" class="proposal"> ' + value + '</label></span><br/>';          
        $("#alternativeLoginProposals").html(proposals).slideDown();
    }); 
}
```

Does someone get the same problem and maybe knows how to fix it?

Comment: Solution wasn't the ajax function, it was a conflict with multiply event inside the next input tag.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without seeing the whole code but I guess you are validating on submit. Did you make sure to use the following code if the validation fails?

```
return false;
```